# How do I add apostrophe before name?

Tags: facebook

Notice many, many ZW users have an apostrophe (') before their name and I wish to have the same.

When I go to Account settings and try to edit my name, enter password, ask for change, it comes up with message that there are too many apostrophes in the name.

It appears that adding this apostrophe improves the game.  I am currently using a nickname (Abby) as a first name, which from what I read is acceptable.  Many of my childhood and high school friends knew me as Abby Norma instead of just Norma.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

(Abby) is fine and acceptable. Using an apostrophe before your name is being used as an SEO hack by some users so I would imagine Facebook wanting to prevent this.

You can also use an alternate name as given in the [Facebook settings](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=account&section=name&t)

[image: Alternate name]